# Create a StandardValueSet via Tooling API

Tags: apex, rest, tooling-api

I am currently working on `StandardValueSet` and I would like to try to insert an entry in the said resource. I looked at the documentation and it sort of lacks the necessary information for me to be able to perform a POST request. I am looking for the information like what would be the payload form and contents.

Referred documentation from Tooling API: [StandardValueSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_standardvalueset.htm)

Am I missing something? Or is there a better documentation for this?

**UPDATE**

I was able to get a response by doing a GET call to this URL:

*/services/data/v43.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+id,durableid,metadata,fullname,masterlabel+FROM+StandardValueSet+where+masterlabel='ContractStatus'*

So I guess the payload for the POST call would be the Metadata part of the response? The problem is I can't find a field which I need from the response. I need the `StatusCode` field which is present in the SOQLXplorer.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: [Query the resource](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/188166/retrieving-standardvalueset-with-the-tooling-api) to see the payload, then try creating a new one based on that. Update your question with details of your attempt if you're still stuck.

Comment: I would use the [metadataAPI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_standardvalueset.htm?search_text=standardvalueset)

Comment: @identigral Hi. I've updated my question and I'm a little stuck right now. Maybe you could help me? Thanks!

Comment: @Oneb Not sure what SOQLXplorer is showing you but there's no `StatusCode` field in `StandardValueSet`

Comment: @identigral If you are in SOQLXplorer and you went to the ContractStatus table, there is a `StatusCode` field. I wanted to insert a record in it using toolingAPI POST Rest call in StandardValueSet. Am I on the right track? Or I got it all mixed up?

Comment: Yeah, you're on the right track. Perhaps @superfell can shed some light on SOQLXplorer.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I hope @superfell answers.